# Adjust Mouse Wheel Zoom sensitivity in Microsoft Office 2016

Tags: ms-office, mouse, macos, zoom

In Microsoft Office 2016, it's possible to Zoom In/Out using a Mouse Wheel while holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button.

For some reason the zoom sensitivity is insanely high (probably because of my normal *page scroll* mouse wheel settings, which are quite sensitive). Unfortunately it makes the scroll/zoom function borderline unusable.

- Is there a way to adjust the wheel sensitivity in Microsoft Office 2016 (or Word 2016)?
- Otherwise, is there a way in OS X or using a third-party utility, to adjust sensitivities on a *per-app basis*?

Furthermore: I'm using a Logitech mouse that uses the *Logitech Control Center* utility in *System Preferences*, and holding the mouse's zoom button while zooming with the wheel, exhibits the same sensitive behaviour as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Scroll.

I would prefer not changing the scroll sensitivity in the entire OS X system. I am happy with the page scroll, but for some reason the *wheel zoom* sensitivity in Office is a bit too wild.

Comment: Have you tried cmd and -/+ ?

Comment: @emotality That doesn't work in my version/config of Office. It's probably possible to set up in *Word > Tools > Customize Keyboard* (although I prefer using the mouse).

Comment: LCC is disgusting software. Anyway, back on topic, you should be able to use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to override the wheel's sensitivity on a per-app basis (i.e. leave the default where it is and override it only for Word). If it's not possible to set the sensitivity with Karabiner, you can absolutely use it to map some mouse/keyboard combination to execute Command-+/-.